# Upload Video on youtube from android application

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm working on an application that uses youtube player to play youtube videos, for this purpose i'm using youtube android player api v3,
Now i want to upload videos on youtube using my application, i've found a solution for that purpose, below is the link,

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#upload_a_video

I downlaoded google-api-java-client library, but i can't find any jar file that contains these classes

```
import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoSnippet;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoStatus;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
```

can you please help me, or give me any idea how can i do this thing, 
thanks

Comment: i integrated youtube player successfuly and videos are playing now, but i need to upload videos, and i really don't know how can i do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look into the following **links** and you will get an idea about uploading an video in you tube.

[android youtube upload video with static username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246212/android-youtube-upload-video-with-static-username-and-password/10432215#10432215)

[YouTube API 3 Upload Video - Access not configured - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022444/youtube-api-3-upload-video-access-not-configured-android)

Also here i will provide you a demo project link as same as you required.

https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android

just go through it and hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research I finally was successful ,

check out [sample project](https://github.com/Redman1037/YoutubeUploadSample)

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener;
import com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.ExponentialBackOff;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTubeScopes;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoSnippet;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoStatus;
import com.nabinbhandari.android.permissions.PermissionHandler;
import com.nabinbhandari.android.permissions.Permissions;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
    private TextView mOutputText;
    private Button mCallApiButton;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int CAPTURE_RETURN = 1;
    private static final int GALLERY_RETURN = 2;


    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
    static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;


    private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";

    private static final String[] SCOPES = {YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY, YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_UPLOAD};

    /**
     * Create the main activity.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState previously saved instance data.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCallApiButton = findViewById(R.id.mCallApiButton);
        mOutputText = findViewById(R.id.tv_outputText);


        // Initialize credentials and service object.
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());


        mCallApiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Permissions.check(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,
                                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        "Accounts and Storage permissions are required ", new Permissions.Options()
                                .setSettingsDialogTitle("Warning!").setRationaleDialogTitle("Info"),
                        new PermissionHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onGranted() {
                                mCallApiButton.setEnabled(false);
                                mOutputText.setText("");
                                getResultsFromApi();
                                mCallApiButton.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });


            }
        });


    }


    /**
     * Attempt to call the API, after verifying that all the preconditions are
     * satisfied. The preconditions are: Google Play Services installed, an
     * account was selected and the device currently has online access. If any
     * of the preconditions are not satisfied, the app will prompt the user as
     * appropriate.
     */
    private void getResultsFromApi() {

        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            acquireGooglePlayServices();
        } else if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
            chooseAccount();
        } else if (!isDeviceOnline()) {
            mOutputText.setText("No network connection available.");
        } else {
//            new SaveTokenAsync().execute();
            mOutputText.setText("Credentials Initialized");

            initVideoPicker();
        }
    }


    private void chooseAccount() {
        String accountName = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
        if (accountName != null) {
            mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

//                new SaveTokenAsync().execute();

            getResultsFromApi();
        } else {
            // Start a dialog from which the user can choose an account
            startActivityForResult(
                    mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                    REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Called when an activity launched here (specifically, AccountPicker
     * and authorization) exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
     * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
     *
     * @param requestCode code indicating which activity result is incoming.
     * @param resultCode  code indicating the result of the incoming
     *                    activity result.
     * @param data        Intent (containing result data) returned by incoming
     *                    activity result.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    mOutputText.setText(
                            "This app requires Google Play Services. Please install " +
                                    "Google Play Services on your device and relaunch this app.");
                } else {
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                        data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName =
                            data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {

                        mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);


                        SharedPreferences settings =
                                getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                        editor.apply();

                        getResultsFromApi();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
                break;


            case CAPTURE_RETURN:
            case GALLERY_RETURN:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    new UploadVideoAsync(data.getData()).execute();
                }
                break;

        }
    }



/*    public class SaveTokenAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                token = mCredential.getToken();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return token;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            if (s != null) {
                SharedPreferences settings =
                        getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                editor.putString(Constants.TOKEN, token);
                editor.apply();

                Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN = token;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Token empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }*/


   /* private void initCaptureButtons() {


        btnCaptureVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureVideo);
        btnCaptureVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
                startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_RETURN);
            }
        });

        btnSelectFromGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectFromGallery);
        btnSelectFromGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("video/*");

                List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                if (list.size() <= 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "no video picker intent on this hardware");
                    return;
                }

                startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_RETURN);
            }
        });

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSelectFromGallery.setEnabled(true);
        btnCaptureVideo.setEnabled(true);
    }*/


    private String uploadYoutube(Uri data) {

        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
//        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new AndroidJsonFactory(); // GsonFactory
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        HttpRequestInitializer initializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                mCredential.initialize(request);
                request.setLoggingEnabled(true);
//                request.setIOExceptionHandler(new HttpBackOffIOExceptionHandler(new ExponentialBackOff()));
            }
        };

        YouTube.Builder youtubeBuilder = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, initializer);
        youtubeBuilder.setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name));
//        youtubeBuilder.setYouTubeRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer(API_KEY));
        YouTube youtube = youtubeBuilder.build();

        String PRIVACY_STATUS = "unlisted"; // or public,private
        String PARTS = "snippet,status,contentDetails";

        String videoId = null;
        try {
            Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();
            videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(new VideoStatus().setPrivacyStatus(PRIVACY_STATUS));

            VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            snippet.setTitle("CALL YOUTUBE DATA API UNLISTED TEST " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            snippet.setDescription("MyDescription");
            snippet.setTags(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"TaG1,TaG2"}));
            videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);

            YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos().insert(
                    PARTS,
                    videoObjectDefiningMetadata,
                    getMediaContent(getFileFromUri(data, MainActivity.this)));/*.setOauthToken(token);*/
//                    .setKey(API_KEY);

            MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();
            uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

            MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener progressListener = new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {
                public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
                    Log.d(TAG, "progressChanged: " + uploader.getUploadState());
                    switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
                        case INITIATION_STARTED:
                            break;
                        case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                            break;
                        case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                            break;
                        case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                        case NOT_STARTED:
                            Log.d(TAG, "progressChanged: upload_not_started");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
            uploader.setProgressListener(progressListener);

            Log.d(TAG, "Uploading..");
            Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
            Log.d(TAG, "Video upload completed");
            videoId = returnedVideo.getId();
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("videoId = [%s]", videoId));
        } catch (final GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException availabilityException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException", availabilityException);
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("UserRecoverableAuthIOException: %s",
                    userRecoverableException.getMessage()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException", e);
        }

        return videoId;

    }

    public class UploadVideoAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        Uri data;

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;


        public UploadVideoAsync(Uri data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Video to youtube");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            return uploadYoutube(data);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "VideoId is " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("VideoId", "" + s);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


    //<--------------------Utils---------------->


    /**
     * Checks whether the device currently has a network connection.
     *
     * @return true if the device has a network connection, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

    /**
     * Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date.
     *
     * @return true if Google Play Services is available and up to
     * date on this device; false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        final int connectionStatusCode =
                apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        return connectionStatusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to resolve a missing, out-of-date, invalid or disabled Google
     * Play Services installation via a user dialog, if possible.
     */
    private void acquireGooglePlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        final int connectionStatusCode =
                apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
            showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Display an error dialog showing that Google Play Services is missing
     * or out of date.
     *
     * @param connectionStatusCode code describing the presence (or lack of)
     *                             Google Play Services on this device.
     */
    void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
            final int connectionStatusCode) {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        Dialog dialog = apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(
                MainActivity.this,
                connectionStatusCode,
                REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
        dialog.show();
    }


    private static File getFileFromUri(Uri uri, Activity activity) {

        try {
            String filePath = null;

            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA);
                filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            }

            cursor.close();

            File file = new File(filePath);
            cursor.close();
            return file;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    private AbstractInputStreamContent getMediaContent(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(
                "video/*",
                new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
        mediaContent.setLength(file.length());

        return mediaContent;
    }


    private void initVideoPicker() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("video/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (list.size() <= 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "no video picker intent on this hardware");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No video picker found on device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_RETURN);

    }


}
```

**Build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev195-1.23.0'
compile 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'

compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mCallApiButton"
        android:text="Upload Video "
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Upload Video"
        android:id="@+id/tv_outputText"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: getting video id=null

Comment: @SågärŚåxëńá did you solve the issue. am also getting the same, Where to load the client id json.